# Server 2012 fails redirected printing in some users

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 providing remote sessions to multiple users. Only one of them have printing problems. It worked fine until few weeks ago. Now, sometimes they can print fine, but very often they get the following error:

"An internal communication error occurred.  Redirected printing will no longer function for a single user session.  Check the status of the Remote Desktop Device Redirector in the System folder of Device Manager."

The Event ID is 1103, and the word is 0000: 0000048F 00000502. Some Webs explains that the last digits, 0x502, is the error code, but I cannot find the definition for 0x502 in any web.

The user only can close the session and start it again to be able to print again.

Other websites explain that a solution is to reinstall Terminal Services in the server, but I am reluctant because other others do not have any problem.

What else I could check?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727392(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Can you try another driver for the printer being used by the user?